# シェルスクリプトで実行ファイルと同じ名前のバイナリーファイルを生成する方法

Tags: shellscript

現在はテキストをバイナリーファイルに変換するというプログラムはあるので、考え方として一度.pyファイルの実行結果をtxtファイルに入れ、txtファイルをバイナリーファイルに変換する。

```
for file in `\find . -maxdepth 1 -type f`; do
  ./$file > a.txt
  cat a.txt |txt2bin.py -i ${file%.*}
  rm a.txt
done
```

しかし${file%.*}があってないのか、バイナリーファイルが生成しません。
実行ファイルの名前を使って新しいファイルを作る方法を教えていただけないでしょうか。

---

mjyさんが提案したset -xで確認したところ、例えばmmat.pyのとき、

```
+ cat a.txt
+ txt2bin.py -i ./mmat
```

と、ファイル名が./ついていることが気づきました。

なのでコードを以下のように書き換えました。

```
for file in `\find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.py"`; do
  ./$file > a.txt
  str=${file%.*}
  str2=${str##*/}
  cat a.txt |txt2bin.py -i $str2
  rm a.txt
done
```

実行した結果、表示では

```
+ for file in `\find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.py"`; do
+ ././mmat.py
+ str=./mmat
+ str2=mmat
+ cat a.txt
+ txt2bin.py -i mmat
+ rm a.txt
```

となり、一見問題ない感じだったが、フォルダのなかにはバイナリファイルはまた生成できなかった。

$str2のような書き方をすると名前と認識しないのでしょうか？何か解決方をお願いいたします。

Comment: txt2bin.py に`-i`オプションで指定するのは出力ファイル名という事でよいですか？また「実行ファイル」のファイル名には拡張子がある事が保証されていますか？（上書きが恐いので）

Comment: -i オプションはinteger指定です(無視して構いません)。
実行ファイルはpythonファイルです。バイナリーファイルは拡張子ありません。

Comment: エラーメッセージは無くて、何のファイルも生成されていない、という事でよいですか？ `fi`と行末の`$`はコピペミスですか？

Comment: はい、そうです。

Comment: 確認ですが`fi`もコピペミスですよね？

Comment: はい、すみません

Comment: 2行目の `$file` ですが、`./$file`のコピペミスだったりしますか？ それともカレントディレクトリにパスが通っている環境ですか？

Comment: コピペミス多くてすみません。おっしゃる通りです。実行していた時は./付けてたので結果に影響出てません。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

まず、txt2bin.py の挙動を確認して下さい。

```
# out.bin が生成されるか
echo "hello" |txt2bin.py -i out.bin
```

問題なければループの挙動を確認。

```
# set -xでもいいですが
# ループで何が実行されているか確認
for file in `\find . -maxdepth 1 -type f`; do
    echo "./$file > a.txt"
    echo "cat a.txt |txt2bin.py -i ${file%.*}"
    echo "rm a.txt"
done
```

これも問題なければ実行ファイルの出力を見てみる。

```
for file in `\find . -maxdepth 1 -type f`; do
    ./$file > a.txt
    # バイナリだと端末が乱れるので cat に -v を付けて(ついでに行番号も付けて)確認
    cat -nv a.txt
done
```

こんな感じでだいたい分かると思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
txt2bin.pyとループを確認しましたが、正常に動いています。a.txtも毎回正確に出ています。
${file%.*}のところを書き換え適当な名前をつけるとちゃんとバイナリーファイルは出ます。
シェルスクリプトは習ったばかりなので、${file%.*}と言う書き方はネットで参照しました。本当に正しいかはよく分かりません。
なのでシェルが${file%.*}という書き方に間違い、または認識できないからoutputファイルが出なかったと思い、質問しました。

Comment: "${file%.*}" のようにダブルクォーテションで括っておかないと、空白が含まれていた時まずい、という問題はありますね。他には問題なさそうですが。

Comment: もう一度確認して問題を見つけ修正しましたが、バイナリーファイルはやはり生成できませんでした。
追加の質問文書に記述しました。

Comment: 解決できました。

Comment: @yoppy どのようなミスを発見し、どのように解決できたか簡単でいいので暇な時にでも追記しておいて下さい。